# Is there a Chrome extension that would allow me to re-focus a tab when I click on a link that is still open?

Tags: chrome, web-browser

Example scenario:

I'm in a Wikipedia-reading frenzy, middle-mouse-clicking many article links and thus opening dozens of tabs while I'm reading. When I switch tabs and click a link that is already open in a tab, instead of it being opened again as a duplicate when I middle-click, I'd like this extension to re-focus the already open tab, thus avoiding unnecessary duplication of tabs. Is this possible somehow?

Additionally, optionally, I'd like these links to have some kind of highlighting to indicate that I still have them open in a tab somewhere. E.g. they could be green instead of blue, or have a green outline, or something else.

Additionally still, if this could work with bookmarks as well, that would be splendid! Too often I still have a bookmark pinned in another window, and I'd rather just focus it instead of re-opening it. Or if someone knows a solution that is independent from the above requirements but is able to solve at least the bookmark situation, I'm all ears all the same.

In closing, I also have some experience with making Google Chrome extensions, so I would also be interested in collaborating to write this with someone if such extension doesn't exist, and there is interest on the part of others. Or if all else fails, but there is still interest in using such an extension, I might set out to write it by myself as well; so please leave a comment indicating your level of interest.

p.s. If you only know about such an addon for Firefox, please do share that at least.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clutter-free-prevent-dupl/iipjdmnoigaobkamfhnojmglcdbnfaaf sounds like it's what you're looking for :) (without the extra colour stuff, but should work for bookmarks too)